# Running Drupal on lighttpd

Tags: lighttpd, drupal, drupal-6

If I run Drupal on lighttpd webserver, I still have all features or I'm going into some limitations ?

For examples, what could be the major issues or any drawback to use it together with Drupal ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using Drupal with FreeBSD and lighttpd + fastcgi + MySQL on [my site](http://jaba.mbnet.fi/ahoy-mate) since 2008. It's been a hassle-free configuration. And my server is only a Pentium III with 512 MB RAM and some ssssssslowwwwwww HD. :)

One limitation that comes to my mind is that Drupal module [Boost](http://drupal.org/project/boost) is only semi-supported with lighttpd and requires some trickery to get it working. If you don't need Boost, everything's should be quite smooth.

Comment: Ok thanks. what about all other modules.. I dunno.. imageMagick.. ImageField Cropping / Upload. I guess they are more PHP related.. but I just want to be sure everything will work you know..

Comment: Boost is really the only module I know having issues. I don't have THAT many extra modules installed, but some of course: CCK, some AJAX modules, couple of image modules, nodewords, sphinx, captcha, some XML sitemap stuff. Everything works. Go on and setup your test server with lighttpd, or if you have an existing server, you can setup lighttpd to another ip address or another port and give it ago behind the curtains and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Lighttpd since 2006 on different servers, it's fast, it handles a lot of traffic and doesn't need much memory. PHP Fastcgi support works out-of-the-box and you don't need to care about spawning processes. For the rewrite stuff check out this site: http://drupal.org/node/43782 (also read the comments)

Answer (score 1):

http://groups.drupal.org/lighttpd is a good resource if your running lighttpd with drupal

http://groups.drupal.org/node/22787

http://groups.drupal.org/node/25453